# Python Celery Autoscaling Kubernetes

Tags: python, kubernetes, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, celery

I'm currently using AWS EBS but switching over to Kubernetes for managing our celery worker pool. According to the Celery documentation when you want to stop a celery worker there are [two types of signals that can be sent to the worker](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#stopping-the-worker). One being **TERM** and another being **KILL**. When **TERM** is used it waits for the worker to finish what it is currently executing before stopping. When **KILL** is used to stops it immediately and this **can cause the loss of tasks**. My question is with Kubernetes autoscaling when scaling down the worker pool, how do I ensure TERM is sent to the workers rather than KILL? I was experiencing this scale down problem with AWS EBS also where Celery flower was showing the loss of tasks when scaling down.

Comment: I also have the same issue! I have auto scaled celery workers' deployment based on number of messages in task queue. As soon as all the messages get consumed by workers it starts to scale down and the celery workers still have uncompleted tasks running in them. Any solution to this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chain of events here is:

1. The HorizontalPodAutoscaler decreases the `replicas:` on the Deployment it controls.
2. The Deployment decreases the `replicas:` on its corresponding ReplicaSet.
3. The ReplicaSet deletes Pods as required.
4. Kubernetes sends each container SIGTERM and waits for it to shut down.
5. If the container hasn't already exited, it sends each container SIGKILL.

The shutdown sequence in particular is described in [Termination of Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination).  Your process will get SIGTERM, and then SIGKILL 30 seconds later if it hasn't already exited.  Nothing is special about the HPA deleting a pod as opposed to any other path.

Comment: if the existing process takes longer time than 30 seconds after receiving SIGTERM then I lose the task because of automatic SIGKILL 30 sec later. Is there any way to avoid it ? (My pods are running a long task taking > 1 hr to complete and they have been autoscaled based on number of pending messages in the Task Queue)

Comment: hey @sap how did you manage to get HPA to work with queue length?

Comment: @chaws I used redis queue and consequently a redis queue exporter to publish queue length to prometheus. From there I created a custom metric as the 'ratio of number of pending message in queue to number of worker pods' and scaled HPA based on this metric.